# Are there other examples besides wasps' polydnaviruses in which a parasitic species introduces an immunosuppressant virus in the parasite's host?

Tags: virology, parasitology, immunosuppression

An [interesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydnavirus) form of mutualism:

> Parasitoid wasps serve as hosts for the virus, and Lepidoptera serve as hosts for these wasps. The female wasp injects one or more eggs into its host along with a quantity of virus. The virus and wasp are in a mutualistic symbiotic relationship: expression of viral genes prevents the wasp's host's immune system from killing the wasp's injected egg [...]

I'm guessing suppressing the immune system of the host is done by other parasitic species in various ways, but are there any other examples in which a virus is "used" for this purpose?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but Toxoplasmosis leading to loss of aversion of mice towards cats is a _behavioral_ suppression: https://www.nature.com/news/parasite-makes-mice-lose-fear-of-cats-permanently-1.13777#/b1

Comment: Summarizes more related-but-not-quite-the-same systems: https://academic.oup.com/bioscience/article/49/4/311/228949